# How to block ruby exec commands

Tags: ruby, shell

Does anybody know how to block/disable ruby exec commands? There are three commands that execute shell commands in ruby: `exec`, `system`, and `%x()` or ``` `` ```. I want to block/disable these commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
module Kernel
  remove_method :exec
  remove_method :system
  remove_method :`
end
```

It reopens the `Kernel` module and and remove the `exec` and `system` methods.

Comment: could you please help me, where this module is located. I am ruby rvm.

Comment: @PravinMishra this is ruby's kernel module, but you don't have to go to actual file where this code is localed. ruby class/modules are extensible, you can reopen it anywhere in your code, like mentioned above.

Comment: thanks @Sachin, Actually i need this change on my ruby template. Because i am using same template again and again. I want to block from administration side. I am taking look to ruby source code but didn't find this module. any help?

Comment: @PravinMishra, you are not supposed to edit actual file's code!!, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec

Comment: @SachinSingh Better use `undef_method` that  will prevent any calls to the method rather than `remove_method` which removes the method from the child, but still passes through up the inheritance chain.